# Jackson JsonUnwrapped properties collision

Tags: java, jackson

I have two classes with some similar structure:

```
class Outer {
    String id;
    String someOuterProp;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    Inner inner;
}

class Inner {
    String id;
    String someOuterProp;
}
```

`Inner` objects can on cases be independently created, and on other cases be nested within `Outer`. As can be seen both have a field with the same (id) name.

When `Outer` objects are serialized - if inner is not null - `Inner` properties should be unwrapped, hence the `@JsonUnwrapped` usage.

When serializing, I want the `Outer` id value being retained, however this assertion fails:

```
Outer o = new Outer();
o.setId("outerId");
Inner i = new Inner();
i.setId("innerId");
o.setInner(i);
    
Map<?,?> map = objectMapper.convertValue(o, Map.class);
assertEquals("outerId", map.get("id"));
```

So, my question is, how can I flatten the nested object properties while also retaining the containing object values upon property name collisions?

Comment: Do you want to retain both `id` fields, or do you want to discard fields that are duplicated in `Inner`?

Comment: @ernest_k I want to discard the fields duplicated by inner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two things you can do.

**Solution 1: order your properties**

Just specify the order of serialized properties to force `Outer.id` to be written last. When the field is read last during deserialization, it will overwrite preceding values (assuming you're deserializing to a map):

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "inner", "id", "someOuterProp" })
class Outer {

    String id;
    String someOuterProp;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    Inner inner;
}
```

`@JsonPropertyOrder({ "inner", "id"})` forces properties flattened from `inner` to be written first.

**Solution 2: use distinct JSON property names**

Simply prefix names for the `Inner` fields. This will make it write values using unique field names:

```
class Outer {
    String id;
    String someOuterProp;

    @JsonUnwrapped(prefix = "inner.")
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    Inner inner;
}
```

When you serialize an object from this class, you get something like

```
{
  "id" : "a",
  "someOuterProp" : "some",
  "inner.id" : "A",
  "inner.someOuterProp" : "SOME"
}
```

And deserializing this into an `Outer` object will put the right values where they belong. The same will apply to a map resulting from your call to `convertValue`:

```
{id=a, someOuterProp=some, inner.id=A, inner.someOuterProp=SOME}
```